# RegExp capture whole string from the beginning for each match

Tags: regex

Text given:

```
First line bla bla
Second line RANDOM bla bla bla
Third line WORDS bla
```

Want to get two matches:

```
First line bla bla
Second line
```

and

```
First line bla bla
Second line RANDOM bla bla bla
Third line
```

Currently trying this:

```
([\s\S]*?)((?:RANDOM)|(?:WORDS))
```

But I'm getting:

```
First line bla bla
Second line
```

and

```
 bla bla bla 
Third line
```

The question is - hot to make the second match start from beginning of string?
    Third line

Comment: The only way with a regex is to duplicate you pattern and capture the whole pattern into groups. [Here is my suggestion](https://regex101.com/r/hR1wG5/2).

Comment: Thanks for reply! I took your suggestion and made some tests. It turned out that it has problems when there are several occurrences of word in the text. https://regex101.com/r/iO5xD6/1

Comment: The problem is with the conflict between lazy and greedy matching if we start playing with `.*` and `.*?`. I doubt you can achieve what you want with a regex.

Comment: What language? Java, Python, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to get both captured groups:

```
(([\s\S]*?) RANDOM\b[\s\S]*?)(?= WORDS\b)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nX1wW3/1)

This will give 2 groups.

**Group #1:**

```
First line bla bla
Second line RANDOM bla bla bla
Third line
```

**Group #2:**

```
First line bla bla
Second line
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But what if I have an array with words to search for and I don't know the sequence of occurrence for these words in the text?

Answer (score 2):

If you need just to capture text, and you use Java or .NET flavour regex, you can try with:

1. **JAVA**

   ```
   (?s)(?<=^(.{1,9999}))(?=.RANDOM|WORDS)
   ```

   [DEMO](http://fiddle.re/3r5x46)

   In Java you can use intervals with min and max value in lookbehind
   `{min, max}`, it gives you some useful capabilities, but it is also
   rather "ugly", nt too elegant solution. By using exaggerated
   interval (like `{1,999999}`) you can get capabilites similar to
   usage of quantifires `+` or `*`. Also the `s` mode, a DOTALL, is
   necessary for `.` to match also new lines.
2. **NET**

   ```
   (?s)(?<=^(.*))(?=.RANDOM|WORDS)
   ```

   [DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fs)(%3F%3C%3D%5E(.*))(%3F%3D.RANDOM%7CWORDS)&i=First%20line%20bla%20bla%0D%0ASecond%20line%20RANDOM%20bla%20bla%20bla%0D%0AThird%20line%20WORDS%20bla)

   .NET son't have restrictions about content of lookbehind, so you can
   use directly `.*` or `.+`. Again a `s` mode is used. With variation:

   ```
   (?s)(?<=^((?:[^R]|R(?!ANDOM))*))(?=RANDOM)|(?s)(?<=^((?:[^W]|W(?!ORDS))*))(?=WORDS)
   ```

   [DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fs)(%3F%3C%3D%5E((%3F%3A%5B%5ER%5D%7CR(%3F!ANDOM))*))(%3F%3DRANDOM)%7C(%3Fs)(%3F%3C%3D%5E((%3F%3A%5B%5EW%5D%7CW(%3F!ORDS))*))(%3F%3DWORDS)&i=First%20line%20bla%20bla%0D%0ASecond%20line%20RANDOM%20bla%20bla%20bla%0D%0AThird%20RANDOM%20line%20WORDS%20bla)

   to match only to first occurance of given word.